# How can we prevent Rad Autocomplete from accepting Duplicate entry?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik

I have a [Rad autocomplete box][1].

My requirement is that I have to disable entering duplicate entries to the rad autocomplete box.

In my case I have a Languages autocomplete box but I am able to enter the item 'English' multiple times.

I want to ensure it is only entered once.

**Question**: Is there any-way so that if an entry is already there I can remove selected value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client-side [OnClientEntryAdding](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/autocompletebox/client-side-programming/events/oncliententryadding) event and check whether there is an entry with the same text and value in the RadAutoCompleteBox input already. So if there is such entry, you can cancel this event using eventArgs.set_cancel(true); Thus this item will not be added to the entries collection again.

Comment: I want to implement in winforms